Wix V5 HarvestDirectory transform not getting applied
I am migrating a product installer from Wix v3 to WiX v5.0.1 and facing issues applying the transform over here,
I have specified the Tranform path in the wixproj file like this,
  <ItemGroup>
    <HarvestDirectory Include="D:\source\repos\src\Client\ProductName\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows7.0\">
      <ComponentGroupName>MyAppComponents</ComponentGroupName>
      <DirectoryRefId>INSTALLFOLDER</DirectoryRefId>
      <SuppressRootDirectory>true</SuppressRootDirectory>
      <Transform>D:\source\repos\src\Client\Setup2\msi\Exclude.xslt</Transform>
    </HarvestDirectory>
    <BindPath Include="D:\source\repos\src\Client\ProductName\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows7.0\" />
  </ItemGroup>

And Exclude.xslt file looks like this,
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- Copy all elements by default -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Change RegistryValue Root from HKCR to HKCU -->
    <xsl:template match="wix:RegistryValue[@Root='HKCR']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="Root">HKCU</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

I can't tell if your match works but you have to set the attribute first and then apply the templates. Your select attribute was missing 'node()' too.
<!-- Change RegistryValue Root from HKCR to HKCU -->
<xsl:template match="wix:RegistryValue[@Root='HKCR']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="Root">HKCU</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

If you use Visual Studio Professional you could debug the XSLT as described here: Walkthrough, debug an XSLT style sheet

In the xsl:stylesheet element the xmlns:wix attribute needs to be updated from v3 to v4:
xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
xmlns:wix="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
The same needs to be done in the .wxs file.
